# How to select isnull on a column along with other columns while selecting data from a table in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The following query works perfectly fine as sql query. But i'm having trouble in converting this into Yii2 format.

```
SELECT id, name, email, ISNULL(phone) FROM test_users
```

can anyone help me out with this

Comment: Can you share actual code you're using to perform your query?

Comment: add your code to show your efforts

Answer (score 0):

The ISNULL(phone) column is not mapped in your model so try using a proper column alias eg:

```
SELECT id, name, email, ISNULL(phone) phone 
FROM test_users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `addSelect` from `yii\db\Query` class:

```
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Expression;

$testUsers = (new Query())
    ->addSelect("id")
    ->addSelect("name")
    ->addSelect("email")
    ->addSelect(new Expression("ISNULL(phone) AS 'isPhoneNull'"))
    ->from("test_users")
    ->all();
```